# gerrit: push: no changes between prior commit and new commit. Not able to pull changes

Tags: git, gerrit

i try to push my new patch sets of my already made commits. I use the command

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

But now i have the problem, that an already pushed commit was rebased from an other gerrit user using the gerrit webinterface.
So gerrit is telling me:

```
No changes between prior commit xxxx and new commit xxxx
```

Now i thougt i had to pull the rebased patch set to solve that issue. But if i try to

```
git fetch master
```

or

```
git pull
```

git tells me:

```
Already up-to-date
```

so I'm not able to pull the rebased patch set..
Can someone help?

Comment: Can you try to visualize what the commit tree looks like (ASCII art will be fine)? I don't think it's possible to give exact guidance without understanding what things look like.

Comment: `Merged Commit A ---> Commit under review B ---> Commit under review C` 

Commit B was rebased in the webinterface, commit C was locally changed. So i try to push commit C, but gerrit tells commit B has no Changes.  It seams to be this bug: https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2936

Comment: Was your commit C based on the original commit B or the rebased one?

Comment: My commit was based on the original B commit. I think i have to rebase my C commit but i'm not able to rebase it because git thinks my repo is up to date.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "rebase" do you mean a literal rebase (as in `git rebase`)? Your question talks about `git pull` but since that command can be configured to perform rebases instead of merges it's not clear what exactly you did.

Comment: Hmm I understand your problem. If i say rebase, i mean the command. To explain what i mean: I have two branches, my local branch called `master` and a local branch `work_in_progress`. The head of my local `master` branch is the same as `origin/master` (which seems to be the merged commit A). The head of `work_in_progress` is commit C. So i think i had to `fetch` and to `rebase` my `work_in_progress` branch to get the same patch set of commit B like its on the remote repository..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're pushing a new patch set in gerrit, the changes should be on top of the existing commit SHA hash.

Since the rebased commit is local to gerrit (also, probably to the user who rebased it) and has not been submitted to master, you can't directly fetch/pull from master as it does not exists in the remote branch.

You need to fetch the commit from gerrit to your local repo using the gerrit URL and then merging/rebasing your local repo. The gerrit refspec should have the following format.

```
git fetch <Gerrit URL> <refs/changes/<change id>/<gerrit id>/<patch set #>>
```

This git push issue is also reported when we cherry-pick a commit, which applies the changes introduced by some existing commit but creates a new SHA hash, and we try to push changes on top of this new local commit.